# Lazy Loading - (Entity Framework) The Underlying Connection was Closed Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, lazy-loading

I'm trying to implement Lazy loading using Entity framework. I'll admit right upfront I've never done this and am struggling. So everything I'm trying is based on articles I've found here. Basically I'm now getting The underlying connection was closed unexpectedly error message.

When I do a WCF trace, it indicates that there was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org...Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types.

So I've researched the DataContractResolver and am unclear as to how to implement this and further am unclear as to how I know if I'm using a DataContractSerializer. Like I said I'm new to this.

Here is my current code:

```
 public OMBCase GetOMBCaseByCaseId(long caseId)
    {
        //using (AWCTSDBEntities context = new AWCTSDBEntities())
        AWCTSDBEntities context = new AWCTSDBEntities();
        //{
        try
        {
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;
            context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

            var caseRecQuery = (from c in context.Cases
                                where (c.CaseId == caseId && c.SystemTypeCode == SystemCodes.OMB)
                                select c).OfType<OMBCase>();

            var caseRecord = caseRecQuery.Single();
            var soldierDetails = caseRecord.Soldier;
            var soldierAddress = soldierDetails.Addresses.ToList();
            foreach (var p in soldierDetails.Addresses)
            {
                var soldierAddressPurpose = p.AddressPurposes;
                foreach (var ap in soldierAddressPurpose)
                {
                    var purpose = ap;
                }
            }
            var soldierTelehone = soldierDetails.Telephones.ToList();
            var soldierEmail = soldierDetails.Emails.ToList();
            var soldierContacts = soldierDetails.Contacts.ToList();
            foreach (var ca in soldierDetails.Contacts)
            {
                var contactAddress = ca.Addresses;
                foreach (var cp in contactAddress)
                {
                    var contactAddressPurposes = cp.AddressPurposes;
                }
            }
            foreach (var ce in soldierDetails.Contacts)
            {
                var contactEmails = ce.Emails;
            }
            foreach (var ct in soldierDetails.Contacts)
            {
                var contactTelephone = ct.Telephones;
            }
            var personInterviewed = caseRecord.PersonInterviewed;
            var createdByUser = caseRecord.CreatedByUser;
            context.Dispose();
            return (caseRecord);
            //
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            return (null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            WriteToLogFile(e);
            return (null);
            //    }
        }


    }
```

Any guidance that you can provide as to where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Rodney

Comment: What line is it throwing an exception on? Is it after you return the value?

Comment: It is on the return. As I go through the code in the debugger, I see all the values coming back, and all looks good. Then I hit the return and everything dies.

Comment: Look at the values after you call context.Dispose(); I have a feeling that they all go out the window when that happens. Your previous question is similar, is this question along the same lines? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703801/entity-framework-lazy-load-with-multiple-includes

Comment: I tried not using the dispose with the same results. I was thinking the same thing to be honest. But it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: What did the values look like after you called context.Dispose()?

Comment: Without the context.Dispose by record all looks like it is populated correct when I do the return.

Comment: It looks like you are correct, my values are going away. With the context.Dispose() when it hits the return, all the objects which are being lazy loaded have System.ObjectDisposedExceptions. So my next question is what do I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

"Lazy loading" doesn't populate any of your classes until an actual value is requested. It also means that when `context` goes out of scope (or is disposed), the objects from the query are no good.

It looks like your program is doing this:

```
Logic logic logic; // Logic before getting case
var case = GetOMBCaseByCaseId(caseid);
Logic logic logic; // Logic performed on case
```

Lazy loading works best with scenarios like this, where logic is performed before the context goes out of scope:

```
ProcessOMBCaseByCaseId(Int32 caseid)
{
    using (AWCTSDBEntities context = new AWCTSDBEntities())
    {
        var caseRecQuery = (from c in context.Cases
                            where (c.CaseId == caseId && c.SystemTypeCode == SystemCodes.OMB)
                            select c).OfType<OMBCase>(); 

        Logic logic logic; // Logic performed on case
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be showing a little ignorance here, but this call is over in WCF land on the backend server, the logic that consumes it isn't until after it is returned to the front end. So while I see what you are saying I'm just unclear as to how to implement it.